# How do I evenly position content regardless of the length of content?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I am trying to have even amount of empty space on the left and the right of the content. I tried using justify but on different length contents it's creating issues.

Question:  How do I add even amount of empty space on the left and right of content regardless of the length of content? I definitely need to add 15px padding on the left of the content.

See code:

```
<div class="pop">
    Over the weekend, I went to a sunset picnic on a rooftop in Brooklyn. 
    The evening couldn’t have been more picturesque — a group of stylish women
    chatting and lounging on blankets, framed against a lavender and glittering
    cityscape.
</div>

<div class="pop">
    This is just one sentence as an example.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pop {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbGeX/

Update:

I want the content to not look centered but it should look like it has equal amount of padding on the left side and right side.  So the left side should have padding-left: 15px; and the content on the right side should adjust to have the same amount of whitespacing as the left one.  I hope this is clearer.

Comment: In your example, are you technically wanting the second div to be centered and the first div to have left and right padding equal to the left and right padding of the second div once centered?

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/dbGeX/1/

Comment: No, regardless of the length of content it should always be padded left by 15px but for longer texts it should look even.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/dbGeX/10/

Comment: So basically what you're looking for is to have the content centered if there's only 1 line of text, or justified if there's 2 or more lines?

Comment: You said: "on different length contents it's creating issues" ... can you describe what the issue is? PLEASE take a few minutes to write down in detail what you are looking for.  You have 3 people here trying to help you, please respond to their questions and comments.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the jsFiddle you provided? I see 15px of padding on the left and right of content regardless of the length of content. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry guys my internet was done i just got it restored.  Let me clarify what i need.

Comment: Your "clarification" isn't any clearer, maybe a diagram would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `width:80%;` (replace 80 with desired value), combined with `min-width` and max-width` properties to achieve what you want, at the same time maintaining your layout.

If you want just the content to be centered, and the border to be on the outer element, see this [**JSFIDDLE ONE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dbGeX/13/).

Or if you want the content to have the border, see this [**JSFIDDLE TWO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dbGeX/12/).

Hope that this was of some help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making an educated guess at your intentions here, but perhaps you may want to use `display:inline-block` on your styling of ".pop".

[Here's what I'm thinking you want.](http://jsfiddle.net/dbGeX/17/) Here, there is equal padding on both sides of the container, regardless of the length of content contained within.

If I'm wrong about what you're trying to achieve, please let me know and I'll try to help you further!